# Hibernate - mapping external table

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have 2 oracle tables. One of them is an oracle external table and the other a standard oracle table with a primary key. I want to be able to select columns from both tables using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. I am just not sure how to setup the hql mapping for the external table since it doesn't have a primary key.

External Table DDL

```
CREATE TABLE MY_EXTERNAL
(
  TRANSDATE                   VARCHAR2(8),
  ACC_NO                      VARCHAR2(10),
  TRANSID                     VARCHAR2(20),
  ID                          VARCHAR2(16),
  FEE                         NUMBER(17),
  AMOUNT                      NUMBER(17)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
( 
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY MY_EXTERNAL_DIR
  ACCESS PARAMETERS
  (
     RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
     OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  )
  LOCATION ('my_feed.dat')
)
```

DDL for table to join to

```
CREATE TABLE ACCTINFO
(
  SEQ NUMBER(12),
  IDENT     VARCHAR2(16),
  AVAILBAL  NUMBER(17),
  HOLDONOD  CHAR(1)
)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "ACCTINFO_PK" ON ACCTINFO
( SEQ )
CREATE INDEX IDENT_IDX ON ACCTINFO
( IDENT )
```

I want to select everything from `MY_EXTERNAL` and `ACCTINFO` if present using a join from `ID` of `MY_EXTERNAL` to `IDENT` of `ACCTINFO`

I would appreciate any help I can get in setting up the classes and the query

Comment: You don't configure mappings with HQL, you write queries with it. This is a problem of Hibernate mapping, rather than HQL querying.

Comment: I don't know what an external table is, but mapping a table without any unique immutable ID is impossible with Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

using a component collection you don't need a unique id of its own, only the join column

```
<bag name="externals" table="MY_EXTERNAL">
  <key column="id" property-ref="IDENT">
  <composite-element>
    <property name=" transactionDate" column="TRANSDATE" />
    ...
  </composite-element>
</bag>
```